# sodimm, so what? error updating sodimm

Tags: ram, ubuntu-mate, sensors

I bought a dell precision 5610 refurb, 6 core xeon, 32GB ram. I have Ubuntu on it. I keep getting a message: "Error Updating sodimm"
[image]

performance so far seems to be OK, but I don't know what this error message is trying to tell me.
I do not see any ongoing messages in dmesg.
The BIOS shows all 32GB Ram, as does the OS.
Might I have bad RAM? How can I verify the the integrity of the hardware, and or make the notification message stop?

Comment: just wait. it comes up periodically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at my panel applets, and realized I had far more than the 6 indicators for my cpu. I also occurred to me that I have an empty socket for another CPU, but that wing of the board is powered, perhaps its registering sensors? or polling? well whatever, the case, if its an actual hardware problem, I'm sure I'll have further questions. For now, I just right clicked on the panel applet sensor Preferences, and unselected SODIMM. (why is there only 2 sodimm buttons? I have 8 ram slots...)[image]